# My dispatch for changing the state in redux is not called?

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch, flash-message

I am trying to display flash message to the user on the login component after reseting the password. I 've commented axios calls because it's unimportant for this case. I am calling dispatch twice, first to set the state(success msg) and second time to set success to empty string.

This is my resetPassword action where i am calling dispatches:

```
export const resetPassword = values => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const token = window.location.href.split("/")[4];
    const data = {
      password: values.password,
      confirmPassword: values.confirmPassword,
      token
    };
    // let res = await axios.post(API_URL + "/resetuserpassword", data);
    // console.log("resStatus:", res);
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/login";
    dispatch({
      type: RESET_SUCCESS,
      payload:
        "You successfully reset the password , just log in with the new one."
    });
    await sleep(2000);
    dispatch({
      type: RESET_SUCCESS,
      payload: ""
    });
catch (error) {
    console.log("error occured:", error);
```

My ResetPassReducer :

```
import { RESET_SUCCESS } from "../actions/types";

export default (state = { success: "" }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RESET_SUCCESS:
      console.log("RESET_SUCCESS DISPATCHED...");
      return {
        success: action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and my renderMessage func in Login component:

```
renderMessage = () => {
    const error = this.props.error;
    const success = this.props.success;

    if (success) {
      return (
        <FlashMessage duration={5000} style="color">
          <p style={{ color: "green" }}> {success.toString()} </p>
        </FlashMessage>
      );
    }
return null;
  };
```

Comment: What's calling `resetPassword`?

Comment: Why do you `await sleep` between dispatch calls? To display a message? I think you should reconsider your algorithm.

Comment: Yes, to display the message . If I don't set my success state to empty string ,my message will show every time i open login component ,but I want to show only after the password is reseted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You are navigating away before making the dispatch calls. All the code located after the `window.location.href = '...'` won't be executed.

Just move `window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/login";` to the end of your block.

Comment: I forgot to say that my first dispatch with success msg working fine, the problem is second one . If i do what you say i will not get my flash msg ,because my state will be empty string . I want my second dispatch to execute after the flash message is dispayed...

Comment: Ok. The problem is that you are waiting synchronously for sleep to terminate, but meanwhile the navigation is executed. As @Hilmi said, you should reconsider your algo. The flashMessage component has a certain duration, after which it will be unmounted ? Why not change the state in that lifecycle hook ?